# DELETE CASCADE in PostgreSQL extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table "studies" with 14 subtables that are connected to "studies" via a foreign key that refers to the primary key in "studies".
I need to delete all rows from the table "studies" where the column "overall_status" is neither "Recruiting" nor "Not yet recruiting". I need to delete the appropriate rows in the dependent tables, too.
I tried with
`DELETE  from ctgov.studies where overall_status not in ('Recruiting','Not yet recruiting');`
But this takes hours. Is there a faster solution?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the foreign key columns?

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this DELETE statement?

Comment: By the way, you can start with just EXPLAIN, that will show you the query plan and will show you the sequential scans where you expect (?) index scans, it will show triggers that might need attention, etc.

Comment: @FrankHeikens  Alas, just EXPLAIN doesn't show anything about triggers.

Comment: Many people think that when you create `foreign keys` these fields are automatically indexed. But this is not true. You must create indexes for foreign-key fields too. Check your indexes and use `explain analyze` for viewing `query execute plan`.

Answer (score 1):

@a_horse_with_no_name and @Ramin Faracov are right.
I believed that when creating a foreign key, I didn't have to worry about the index.
So when I had this slow query situation, I just created 2 indexes and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE CASCADE was extremely slow in PgAdmin; after an overnight session, I discontinued it. Exactly the same query ran flawlessly in psql. I also reduced the number of indexes before deleting a big number of rows.